# Android animation layout issues

Tags: android, android-animation

I have a RelativeLayout where two LinearLayouts and a TextView (all 3 are children) share the same space, meaning that only one View is Visible while the other two are Gone at any given point. At application startup, the TextView is the Visible View. I have a button that starts an animation which causes the TextView to fade out and a LinearLayout to fade in. There is another button for the other LinearLayout.

The logic is as follows:
Button press -> TextView fade out -> LinearLayout set to Visible -> LinearLayout fade in.
Back Button press -> LinearLayout fade out -> OnAnimationEnd LinearLayout visibility Gone -> TextView fade in

This works perfectly fine as long as the above interactions are with the same button (for the same LinearLayout). As soon as the other LinearLayout's button is pressed, the other LinearLayout is briefly displayed during the TextView's fade out before the proper LinearLayout fades in. The same thing occurs when the back button is pressed: the other LinearLayout is briefly displayed in between fade out and fade in.

Any ideas?

```
fadeOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation......
fadeIn = AnimationsUtils......
fadeOut.setAnimationListener(this)

......
.....

public void buttonOnClick(View v) {
    int id = v.getId();
    switch(id) {
    case R.id.get_started:
        viewState = SIGNUP_STATE;
        toggleWelcomeViews(HIDE);
        toggleSignupViews(SHOW);
        break;
    case R.id.already_have_account:
        viewState = LOGIN_STATE;
        toggleWelcomeViews(HIDE);
        toggleLoginViews(SHOW);
        break;
}

......
....
public void toggleSignupViews(int flag) {
    /*
    int action = (flag == SHOW) ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE; 
    signupForm.setVisibility(action);
    whyPhoneLink.setVisibility(action);
    submitButton.setVisibility(action);
    */

    if (flag == SHOW) {
        if (NetworkConfig.debug) Log.i(LOG_TAG, "fade in signup views"); 
        signupForm.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        whyPhoneLink.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        submitButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        submitButton.setClickable(true);
        signupForm.startAnimation(fadeIn);
        whyPhoneLink.startAnimation(fadeIn);
        submitButton.startAnimation(fadeIn);

    } else {
        if (NetworkConfig.debug) Log.i(LOG_TAG, "fade out signup views"); 
        signupForm.startAnimation(fadeOut);
        whyPhoneLink.startAnimation(fadeOut);
        submitButton.startAnimation(fadeOut);
        signupForm.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        whyPhoneLink.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        submitButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        submitButton.setClickable(false); 
    }

}

......
......

public void onBackPressed() {   
    switch(viewState){
    case WELCOME_STATE:
        // exit app..
        super.onBackPressed();
        break;
    case SIGNUP_STATE:
        // hide signup views and show welcome views
        viewState = WELCOME_STATE;
        leavingState = SIGNUP_STATE;
        toggleSignupViews(HIDE);
        toggleWelcomeViews(SHOW);
        break;
    case LOGIN_STATE:
        // hide login views and show welcome views
        viewState = WELCOME_STATE;
        leavingState = LOGIN_STATE;
        toggleLoginViews(HIDE);
        toggleWelcomeViews(SHOW);
        break;
    }
}

@Override
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
    if (NetworkConfig.debug) Log.i(LOG_TAG, "animation ended");

    if (leavingState == SIGNUP_STATE) {
        signupForm.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        whyPhoneLink.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        submitButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        submitButton.setClickable(false);
    } else if (leavingState == LOGIN_STATE) {
        loginForm.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        forgotPassword.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        submitButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        submitButton.setClickable(false);
    }

}
```

The logic for all the missing toggle...() functions are the same as the one above. I've tried putting the View.GONE code in onAnimationEnd, but the result is the same (the bug still persists).

Comment: What are you doing in animation callback? Show as the code

Comment: pretty much the same thing as in the other functions. check the edit.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of [GONE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#GONE), use, [INVISIBLE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#INVISIBLE).

It's hard to tell you the exact problem when you only provide deltas of code. But I think it some how related to when you register to animation callback. Make sure you unregister in `onAnimationEnd`

Comment: sorry about the code snippets, it's a bit messy but all of the logic is there. what exactly do you mean by unregistering in onAnimationEnd?

Comment: @ynnadkrap It's hard to understand from your code when exactly "fadeOut.setAnimationListener(this)" called. But at some point you need to call: "fadeOut.setAnimationListener(null)", to unregister

Comment: Oh, it's in onCreate, sorry about that. So I need to register/unregister each time I want to use that animation? Also, the animation is being used for multiple views - is this problematic?

Comment: Yes, I suggest to unregister each time you finish using and register deferent animation for each view groups.